SAP RFC call in WCF and . NET 7 via VS 2022 error
I can not manage the following error :
System.InvalidOperationException: ‘’There is no TransportBindingElement in the CustomBinding on the ServiceEndpoint with the negotiation ‘ZQM_XPortType’. Each binding must have at least one binding element derived from a TransportBindingElement.’
I was good in winforms .NET 7 and .NET Framework 4.8 for a long time without any problems.

This is about WCF, not WPF.

From your question, you are missing the TransportBindingElement in custombinding.
You can add the TransportBindingElement by adding the following code to your configuration file:
<bindings>
      <customBinding>
          <binding name="myCustomBinding">
              <compactMessageEncoding>
               <binaryMessageEncoding/>
              </compactMessageEncoding>
              <tcpTransport listenBacklog ="100" 
                            maxBufferPoolSize ="524288" 
                            maxBufferSize ="2147483647" 
                            maxReceivedMessageSize ="2147483647"/>
          </binding>
      </customBinding>

This is the document.
Update
I also have two suggestions:
1.Upgrade your System.Servicemodel version to the highest level.
2.Migrate WCF services to Corewcf.
And replace webhttpbinding with custombinding.
Add in appsettings.json:
{
  "bindings": {
    "customBinding": {
      "type": "TransportBinding",
      "scheme": "http",
      "authenticationScheme": "Basic",
      "maxReceivedMessageSize": 65536
    }
  }
}

Finally, build the host.
var host = new CoreWcf.ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri("......."));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new CoreWcf.WebHttpBinding(), "myService");
host.Open();


TransportBindingElement this is for .NET Framework.
